# How to embed dictionary type data in array in didSelectItemAt IndexPath in swift 4?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsdictionary, swift4

[image][image]

I have `userDetails` data. now i want to sent `userDetails` in `didSelectItemAt IndexPath` to another `viewController`.

How to do that?

Here is my piece of code

```
var userDetails : UserDetails! 


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { 

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell 
let imageUrl = URL(string: Constant.url.imageBaseUrl + userDetails.user_medias[indexPath.row].thumbnail_url) 
cell.imgvw.kf.setImage(with: imageUrl)

return cell 
} 

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constant.vc.DetailsVC) as! DetailsVC
        vc.userDetails = userList[indexPath.row]
        self.show(vc, sender: self)
    }

 // in number of rows in section i am showing this 
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userDetails.user_medias.count
    }
```

How to embed `userDetails` data in `userList` so that i can send data in didselcect item at indexpath

Comment: In `didSelectItemAt` you called show func in last line so What is the show func??

Comment: @dahiya_boy . will you please elaborate sir

Comment: In `didSelectItemAt` you called show func in last line so What is the show func??

Comment: that is responsible for showViewController @dahiya_boy

Comment: Just want to get only the values from dictionary as array ? or convert full dictionary with keys and its values as array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using These cases if it helps you

```
var myDict : [String : String] = ["ios":"1","Geek":"2","IosGeek":"4"]

///First case - Map the Dict
let onlyValues = myDict.map({$0.1})
print(onlyValues) // Print Only Values

///Second Case - Using a Seprate class
class sortData
{
    var iosVal : String!
    var geekVal : String!
    var iosGeekVal : String!

    init(parameter : [String:String]) {
        iosVal = parameter["ios"]
        geekVal = parameter["Geek"]
        iosGeekVal = parameter["IosGeek"]
    }
}

class DestinationVC : UIViewController {
    var passedData : sortData!
}

///Getting Data Using Class
var sortingData : sortData?
sortingData = sortData.init(parameter: myDict)
print(sortingData?.iosVal!) // "1"
/// pass this class in Your destinationVC
/// And Use as
/// sortingData?.iosVal! // sortingData?.geekVal! // sortingData?.iosGeekVal!
```

**Sample Code with comments Please check**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rWeg6PMHQH2oL0wMS1ed9fGkHkvLAIrP

Comment: i am used model class file for json parsing what i am looking is to embed the dictionary type data to an array. please help

Comment: You want to add Dictionary Directly as array ? or only Values ?

Comment: You are using model class Right for parsing json that means you can pass specific fetched UserDetail Object to other controller also , right ?

Comment: actually i want to sent the total userDetails data to another view controller in collectionview didselect

Comment: Thats simple you are already using a modal class and just pass that modal class instance initiated as object on place of Dictionary to other class just Asin my code posted case 2

Comment: Do you need a sample code ? if you feel its difficult to understand

Comment: I uploaded a sample project and wrote comments in code so you can understand what flow I am using to pass dictionary data obtained from son to destination class

Comment: Thank you so much @ios Geek, i am checking

Comment: Did this helped you achieving results ?

Comment: sorry for late reply i am getting to you after some time.

Comment: No issues , take your time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168172/discussion-between-gorib-developer-and-ios-geek).

Answer (score 0):

Create model of userDetails response from http://www.json4swift.com/

Declare yourArray of User Type

```
var yourArray = [User]()
```

In API response use below code:-

```
if let data = data["userDetails"] as? NSArray {                             
    self.yourArray.append(contentsOf: User.modelsFromDictionaryArray(array: data))
}
```

In didSelect method use below code:-

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constant.vc.DetailsVC) as! DetailsVC
vc.userDetails = yourArray[indexPath.row]
self.show(vc, sender: self)
```

Comment: i am using just and object mapper for json parsing. i have create model class. can you tell me what will be the modelsFromDictionaryArray sir @Manish Mahajan

Comment: Go through my first line... I stated create model of userDetails response. User class file will automatically generate just you have put your JSON response in http://www.json4swift.com/

Comment: Okay sir doing it

Answer (score -1):

In `DetailsVC` create an object

```
var myUser : [String : Any] = [:]
```

in `ViewDidLoad`

```
let id = myUser["id"]
let userId =  myUser["user_id"]
let catId =  myUser["category_id"]
```

On `didselect` in FirstVC

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constant.vc.DetailsVC) as! DetailsVC
vc.myUser = userDetails.user_medias[indexPath.row] as! [String : Any]
self.show(vc, sender: self)
```

Comment: but i am unable to embed the userDetails data in your_array @dahiya_boy

Comment: @GoribDeveloper you didn't show me any thing related to this. So first show me what you have done. Then I will edit and re-answer you according to it.

Comment: Look sir i have a api. where after json parsing i am getting the data.after getting the data i am showing the details collection view. like this  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userDetails.user_medias.count
    }

Comment: sir: now just i want to embed the userDetails data to an array so that i can sent it in the indexpath to another view controller

Comment: @GoribDeveloper PLS SHOW ME `CELLFORITEM` FUNC. ADD IN YOUR QUES.

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        let imageUrl = URL(string: Constant.url.imageBaseUrl + userDetails.user_medias[indexPath.row].thumbnail_url)
        cell.imgvw.kf.setImage(with: imageUrl)   
        return cell
    }

Comment: @GoribDeveloper Actually your user data is in `userDetails.user_medias` so you have to pass the according to it. So do like this `vc.myUser = userDetails.user_medias[indexPath.row]` and check my answer.

Comment: how to print the data from myUser in the next view controller?

Comment: @GoribDeveloper It passed the data to nextVC that means now you use myUser in nextVC. To check data do `print(myUser)` in secondVC

Comment: how to print the data inside user_medias? i have post the screenshot

Comment: @GoribDeveloper: Have you passed data successfully to next view controller ?

Comment: @dahiya_boy it is showing Cannot assign value of type 'UserMedias' to type '[String : Any]'

Comment: @GoribDeveloper You have to cast like ` as! [String : Any]` check answer again.